# Post JSON data/object to API using reactive.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to add a JSON data/object to the API using ractive.js but i'm not getting any results. It shows me a response "no content". Not sure what I'm currently missing at the moment. I'm using ractive.js for this project.

This is a sample code that I have been working on.

```
app.on('addLead', function() {
    var proxy        = app.get('proxy');
    var endpoint     = 'account/leads/';
    var rt           = 'POST';
    var url          = proxy+'?endpoint='+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;
    var data         = {
        "isProfiled": true,
        "isBaluarte": 0,
        "isVertical": 0,
        "isAffiliate": 0,
        "isBranch": 0,
        "id": 0,
        "dateRequested": "2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z",
        "accountIdFk": 0,
        "accountLeadId": 1285689131,
        "accountName": "Noel String",
        "assignedEmployeeIdFk": 0,
        "unitNumber": "string",
        "floorNumber": "string",
        "buildingName": "string",
        "streetNumber": "string",
        "streetName": "string",
        "barangayIdFk": 0,
        "cityTownIdFk": 0,
        "provinceIdFk": 0,
        "regionIdFk": 0,
        "leadsIdentifier": "string",
        "salesRegion": "string",
        "egApproval": "string",
        "smsId": "string",
        "dateComSmsId": "2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z",
        "egRemarks": "string",
        "dateComGbuTag": "2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z",
        "sgRemarks": "string",
        "taggingDetailsIdFk": 0,
        "profiling": "string",
        "dateCompletedGbuTag": "2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z",
        "gbuTagidFk": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "latitude": 0,
        "numberOfEmployees": "string",
        "tier": "string",
        "industryTypeIdFk": 0,
        "gbuMigration": "string",
        "finalReco": "string",
        "motherAccountId": 0,
        "remarksFindings": "string",
        "finalCompanyName": "string",
        "accountCategoryIdFk": 0,
        "sourceLeadIdFk": 0,
        "baluarte": true,
        "vertical": true,
        "affiliate": true,
        "branch": true,
        "profiled": true
    };

    $.ajax({
         type    : 'POST',
         url     : url,
         data    : data,
         success : alert('success')
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Chrome Tools Dev Network**

**General**

```
Request URL:http://192.168.1.126/lms-dev-noel/proxy.php?endpoint=account/leads/&rt=POST
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.1.126:80
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:841
Content-Type:text/json
Date:Fri, 13 Jan 2017 02:52:16 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:934
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__atuvc=3%7C51%2C1%7C1; SESSfb2f81a034926ea9559505bfadcce9a3=RcchjmRlh0jHPn4LuTES7YMkAHnKbsotRdHIo2Gtbqw; SESS2b177789a8b29da818933ad27543b7ad=zjWnvbr75ZMuZMnwVXCb6PGkRzg8eTP0C2dCeaBZ9Sw; _ga=GA1.1.1071659288.1482134344
Host:192.168.1.126
Origin:http://192.168.1.126
Referer:http://192.168.1.126/lms-dev-noel/site/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Query String Parameters**

```
endpoint:account/leads/
rt:POST
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
isProfiled:true
isBaluarte:0
isVertical:0
isAffiliate:0
isBranch:0
id:0
dateRequested:2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z
accountIdFk:0
accountLeadId:1285689131
accountName:Noel String
assignedEmployeeIdFk:0
unitNumber:string
floorNumber:string
buildingName:string
streetNumber:string
streetName:string
barangayIdFk:0
cityTownIdFk:0
provinceIdFk:0
regionIdFk:0
leadsIdentifier:string
salesRegion:string
egApproval:string
smsId:string
dateComSmsId:2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z
egRemarks:string
dateComGbuTag:2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z
sgRemarks:string
taggingDetailsIdFk:0
profiling:string
dateCompletedGbuTag:2017-01-12T07:13:19.717Z
gbuTagidFk:0
longitude:0
latitude:0
numberOfEmployees:string
tier:string
industryTypeIdFk:0
gbuMigration:string
finalReco:string
motherAccountId:0
remarksFindings:string
finalCompanyName:string
accountCategoryIdFk:0
sourceLeadIdFk:0
baluarte:true
vertical:true
affiliate:true
branch:true
profiled:true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()`.

**JSON.stringify function turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores it in a string.**

On server-side you have to `parse` the string.

See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
app.on('addLead', function(event) {
var proxy        = app.get('proxy');
var endpoint     = 'account/leads';
var rt           = 'POST';
var url          = proxy+'?endpoint'+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;
data: JSON.stringify({
    "id": 10,
    "dateRequested": "2017-01-12",
    "accountIdFk": 0,
    "accountLeadId": 1305981891,
    "accountName": "Noel String",
    "assignedEmployeeIdFk": 10007901,
    "unitNumber": "23",
    "floorNumber": "12",
    "buildingName": "Emerald",
    "streetNumber": "123457",
    "streetName": "Est Street",
    "barangayIdFk": 0,
    "cityTownIdFk": 0,
    "provinceIdFk": 0,
    "regionIdFk": 0,
    "leadsIdentifier": "string",
    "salesRegion": "string",
    "egApproval": "string",
    "smsId": "string",
    "dateComSmsId": "2017-01-09",
    "egRemarks": "string",
    "dateComGbuTag": "2017-01-09",
    "sgRemarks": "string",
   }),
});
```

Comment: It seems your url is wrong: `proxy+'?endpoint'+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;`. Please change to this : `proxy+'?endpoint='+endpoint+'&rt='+rt;`. You forgot `=` after `endpoint`.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors on the console and I already changed the URL before you pointed it out

Comment: It is hitting your method ?

Comment: Your `data` is an object.In order to pass to server-side you need to use `JSON.stringify`. `data    : JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: I tried that solution and the result is still the same. It shows me a response "no content"

Comment: It is hitting your method ?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what do you mean by "hitting your method"

Comment: I mean if your method from `server-side` it's called.

Comment: Yes I think so, but I seem to be getting an error 400. I have included the result of the method:POST in the description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133046/discussion-between-clestcruz-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).